# Does Firebase Analytics support geographic drill down?

Tags: google-analytics, firebase, firebase-analytics

I've created a Firebase account and integrated it into an app. In the Firebase Console, I can see a map of the world, and yes, there's the app running in USA(where I am).

There does not seem to be any finer geographic granularity than "country". The similar feature in Google Analytics lets you click on a country and see the data to city level. Am I missing something, or is country-level usage the finest granularity available with Firebase Analytics?

And if it can do better, how?

Comment: Note that around 2017 Q1, a new feature called "Streamview" went into beta within the Firebase console. This provides very geo-granular live tracking of usage. It does not, however, provide data over a range of time like "last 7 days" or "last 30 days". It is only instant/live.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, you can't see finer granularity in Firebase Analytics. However, finer-grained granularity (Region and City) is available in BigQuery, so if you need that level of detail, you can link your Firebase app to BigQuery and access it there.

Comment: I was suspecting this was the answer. Unfortunately, BigQuery export is only available on the non-free "Blaze" or "Flame" tier (at $300/year).

Comment: As you mentioned, BigQuery is available on the Blaze (pay only for usage) tier and BigQuery offers a free query tier of 1 TB/month.  It's surprisingly affordable and worth considering.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

Comment: As of September 2017, you still can **NOT** export a CSV or create a report **in Firebase to view users city location?**  Marketing will **really** not like Firebase.  Firebase is a step backwards with respect to geolocation.  **Google Analytics could view down to the city resolution. Really ?**

Comment: I signed up for the paid BigQuery service. For the several hundred users I'm looking at, they occasionally bill me 0.01 USD. I guess that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It is already available after you creating a new view in Google Analytics with connected Firebase.

[image: Cities and country in Firebase]

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends what your using Firebase for. If you're interested in Firebase geo analytics for the web then you might want to check out https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/06/geofire-20.html for more information.

Comment: I'm not attempting to code additional tracking functionality. I'm asking whether the standard Firebase admin console has the ability to drill down further than "country" like Google Analytics admin console does. I don't need to pin any user down to a street or house... but I need better than "What continent are they on?" as America is pretty huge.